# Having trouble counting page views using "impressionist" gem (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

**Update #2**
I've got it working but how can I make it count each refresh? Even if I refresh on a user's profile (/users/3 for example), I want it to count.

Widget.rb

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  is_impressionable

  def impressionist_count
    impressions.size
  end
  end
```

Widgets controller

```
WidgetsController < ApplicationController


def show
  @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
  impressionist(@widget,message:"wtf is a widget?") #message is optional
end

 end
```

Added Is_Impressionable to the user model

and here's the code I'm using for show.html.erb view

```
<%= @user.impressionist_count(:filter=>:all) %>
```

**Update #1**
When I make the change noted below in Said's answer and try it in the "Widgets" controller and "Widget" module, I get this error now:

```
    NoMethodError in Users#show
undefined method `impressionist_count' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's the user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :impressions, :as=>:impressionable
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name: "Relationship",
                                   dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  before_save { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end

  def feed
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
  end

  def impressionist_count
    impressions.size
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
  end
```

and here's the Users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user,
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy


  def index

    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page]).all
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])

  end



  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Demoapp!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed"
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def following
    @title = "Follow"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end


  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

**Original Post**
What did I do wrong below?

I added the gem and ran the db migration.

Then I created a new "Widgets" controller file in app\controllers

```
WidgetsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @widget = Widget.find
    impressionist(@widget) 
  end
end
```

Then I created a new "Widget" model in app/models

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  is_impressionable
end
```

Then I added

```
<%= @widget.impressionist_count %>
```

in the **show.html.erb** view

What I am trying to count is the # of user's profile views. Throughout the website, you can click on a username and it will go into their profile. I just want to show the counter of how many times were clicked into their profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the problem is in show action,
instead:

```
  @widget = Widget.find
```

try this

```
  @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
```

**UPDATE: 1**

you should add **is_impressionable** to your user model

Comment: Do these codes go into the "Widgets" controller and "Widget" model? or the "Users" controller and "User" model? When I try it with the "Widgets" I get: NoMethodError in Users#show undefined method `impressionist_count' for nil:NilClass. Which makes me try it in "Users" instead but it gives me this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in UsersController#show
Could not find table 'widgets

Comment: it's in widgets controller

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that. I get this error message: undefined method `impressionist_count' for nil:NilClass. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Log an impression per model instance in your controller. Note that it is not necessary to specify "impressionist" (usage #1) in the top of you controller if you are using this method. If you add "impressionist" to the top of your controller and also use this method in your action, it will result in 2 impressions being logged (but associated with one request_hash)

Comment: Can you tell me how to log an impression per model instance in the controller? I'm really new to this, sorry. Also, I have posted all of the information where I'm currently at in the updated original post

Comment: Thanks Said. I've got it working now but I don't think it's counting my page views much at all. I was only able to get +1 view after various tries. Can you look over my update #2?

Comment: you actually don't need widgets model and controller, you can add impressionist actions: [:index, :show] to your users controller and in your model add: is_impressionable, and then you'll be able to access: impressionist_count, according to your instance var, ex: in your case: @user.impressionist_count